# How to update record in DB using namedqueries

Tags: jpa, derby, named-query

I would like to know how to create an update named query to update a record in a derby db.

Here is my scenario, i have a table called account in a database named bank. 
In the account table there are 2 columns, account id and balance.

I want to type an update query which will update the balance of a record using the account id.
I am familiar with sql queries but not with named queries.

Here is what I have created

```
@NamedQuery(name="Accountcb004415.updateBalance",
  query="UPDATE Accountcb004415 
  set a.balance = :balance WHERE a.accountid= :accountid")
```

However the above query doesn't work. 
What seems to be wrong here ?

Comment: @Amrola: Where did you get that idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you have missed *identification variable* `a` in the query definition. In other words entity name needs to be aliased with value `a`. Try this:

```sql
UPDATE Accountcb004415 a
  set a.balance = :balance WHERE a.accountid= :accountid
```